# Any .NET load-test tool available apart from VS2010 Ultimate?

Tags: .net, load-testing

Are there some tools which basically do the same as the VS2010 Ultimate load testing tool?

Anyone knows if there is a port of jload or any other open-source load testing tools?

Comment: Sorry, I have never looked into the loadtest capabilities of VS2010, but you might want to have a look at Apache JMeter (http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), which although written in Java, allows to loadtest WebServices, WebSites, etc. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- The Grinder ([http://grinder.sourceforge.net/](http://grinder.sourceforge.net))
- tsung (http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- BadBoy (http://www.badboy.com.au/)
- Oracle Application Test Suite (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index.html)

I fooled around with each one as a possible load testing alternative.  They all feature distributed testing (except BadBoy, I think) and have interesting features, but none were compelling enough to overcome the large investment (anchor?) I already have in VS.